# Frame Alignment From Right with sizeToFit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am making a chat UI. I have created a textview for showing Text Messages.
When i am Using sizeToFit For textview. it always sizeToFit from X(Left) Edges. i need to set Small messages from Right Side of view .

[image]

Here is my code for Textview.

```
  UITextView *TextLbl = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width-220, cell.frame.origin.y, 210, 60)];
 TextLbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
  TextLbl.contentMode=UIViewContentModeRight;
 TextLbl.editable=NO;
  [TextLbl sizeToFit];
  [TextLbl.textContainer setSize:TextLbl.frame.size];
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this either use layout constraints or calculate the size of text the set the same size for textview and x will be screenWidth-textview.width.

**EDIT**

Add constraints as shown in code below:

```
UITextView *TextLbl = [[UITextView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:TextLbl];
[TextLbl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextLbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TextLbl.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:-10]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextLbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:TextLbl.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:-10]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextLbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TextLbl.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:100]];

[TextLbl setText:@"Hello there!"];
[TextLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
TextLbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
TextLbl.contentMode=UIViewContentModeRight;
TextLbl.editable=NO;
TextLbl.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

You may tweak constraint as per your layout.

Comment: Can you Please Refer me to any helpfull Link.. i am stuck on that point

Comment: reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint

Answer (score 0):

Solution--

```
- (void)sizeToFitWithAlignmentRight :(UILabel *)label {
CGRect beforeFrame = label.frame;
[label sizeToFit];
CGRect afterFrame = label.frame;
label.frame = CGRectMake(beforeFrame.origin.x + beforeFrame.size.width - afterFrame.size.width, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`-sizeToFit` sets the CGSize of the UITextView, but does nothing to modify where in the superview the element is placed. Depending on your selected layout system (autolayout, etc) there are different ways you can achieve you textviews nestled against the right edge.

Comment: How can i set alignment Right of frame.?